# Calculate user session from a long format table: performance issue with straight forward approach

Tags: r

I would need to calculate session durations for some users.
To make it simple, users can switch on or off, and I need to measure how long they stayed on.
The table I get is pretty simple:
 ,  ,

I tried a simple method, by ordering by time stamps, and also using by function to actually calculate differences between consecutive lines, for each user.
This works, however my real data contains thousands and thousands of lines, and it ends up being very slow (already managed to kill my laptop memory). 
I roughly work with about 300000 lines in this table, and 5000 different user names.

Is there any way to get something faster than the code below?

```r
#Synthetic data
connections<-data.frame(name=c("sam","sam","bob","mike","bob","mike","sam","sam","bob","mike","bob","mike"),
                        state=c("on","off","on","on","off","off","on","off","on","on","off","off"),
                        time= c("2019-06-19 00:00:02","2019-06-19 01:11:22",
                                "2019-06-19 10:09:19","2019-06-19 02:12:06",
                                "2019-06-19 10:45:18","2019-06-19 06:24:43",
                                "2019-06-19 14:12:06","2019-06-19 15:15:43",
                                "2019-06-19 17:54:08","2019-06-19 15:17:47",
                                "2019-06-19 19:27:55","2019-06-19 21:22:36"))

#Consider time variable as a time stamp
connections$time<-as.POSIXct(connections$time)
connections<-connections%>%arrange(time)

#calculate the difference between time stamps for all user sessions (on-off transitions)
sessions<-by(connections,connections$name, duration)

#transform list back to a data frame
sessions<-rbindlist(sessions)

#keep only lines corresponding to off factor as, it corresponds to the duration people stayed on
sessions<-sessions[sessions$state=='off',]

#display the table. This result suits me, but on big tables, this code is damn slow...
sessions
```

Expected result is reached with code above, but slowly :-)

```
name state                time session_duration
1:  bob   off 2019-06-19 10:45:18             2159
2:  bob   off 2019-06-19 19:27:55             5627
3: mike   off 2019-06-19 06:24:43            15157
4: mike   off 2019-06-19 21:22:36            21889
5:  sam   off 2019-06-19 01:11:22             4280
6:  sam   off 2019-06-19 15:15:43             3817
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't compare with what you've done, since you haven't shared the code for the `duration` function.  I can update with a comparison if you do that.

Some options are given below.  I tried it with base R (I'm using 3.4.1), using parallel processing, and using `dplyr` (0.7.7, so I'm a little outdated).  I had read once a few ages ago that `dplyr` can get a bit slow when deal with a lot of groups, but I don't know if that's still the case. In this particular example, it seems `dplyr` is still about twice as fast with even 30 groups.  It's margin of superiority grows up through 6000 groups.

I'm sure there's a `datatable` way to do this, but I'm not well versed in that framework, so I won't try to add it myself.

In a problem like this, I'd expect adding more distinct users would cause more slow down than adding more rows per user, and even at 6000 users, I'm still processing this in four seconds using my slowest approach.  That makes me think your `duration` function isn't well optimized to the problem.  I would encourage you to share that code so that we can show you what kind of traps to avoid. (I'm assuming `duration` is a function of your own making, since `?duration` doesn't call anything up for me)

```
# Base R

calculate_duration <- function(df){
  df$end_time <- dplyr::lead(df$time)
  df <- df[df$state == "on", ]
  df$duration <- difftime(df$end_time, df$time, units = "secs")
  df
}

conn <- connections[order(connections$name, connections$time), ]
conn <- split(conn, conn$name)
conn <- lapply(conn, calculate_duration)
conn <- do.call("rbind", conn)
conn

# parallel

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, "calculate_duration")
conn <- connections[order(connections$name, connections$time), ]
conn <- split(conn, conn$name)
conn <- parLapply(cl, conn, calculate_duration)
conn <- do.call("rbind", conn)
conn

stopCluster(cl)

# dplyr

library(dplyr)

connections %>% 
  arrange(name, time) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(end_time = lead(time)) %>% 
  filter(state == "on") %>% 
  mutate(duration = difftime(end_time, time, units = "secs"))
```

### Benchmarks

```
ndup_option <- c(1, 10, 50, 100, 500, 2000)

for (i in ndup_option){
  connections <- data.frame(name = c("sam","sam","bob","mike","bob","mike","sam","sam","bob","mike","bob","mike"),
                            state = c("on","off","on","on","off","off","on","off","on","on","off","off"),
                            time = as.POSIXct(c("2019-06-19 00:00:02","2019-06-19 01:11:22",
                                                "2019-06-19 10:09:19","2019-06-19 02:12:06",
                                                "2019-06-19 10:45:18","2019-06-19 06:24:43",
                                                "2019-06-19 14:12:06","2019-06-19 15:15:43",
                                                "2019-06-19 17:54:08","2019-06-19 15:17:47",
                                                "2019-06-19 19:27:55","2019-06-19 21:22:36")),
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

  ndup <- i
  conn_list <- vector("list", ndup)
  for (j in seq_len(ndup)){
    tmp <- connections
    tmp$name <- sprintf("%s%s", connections$name, j)
    conn_list[[j]] <- tmp
  }

  connections <- do.call("rbind", conn_list)

  out <- microbenchmark(
    base = {
      conn <- connections[order(connections$name, connections$time), ]
      conn <- split(conn, conn$name)
      conn <- lapply(conn, calculate_duration)
      conn <- do.call("rbind", conn)
      conn
    },
    parallel = {
      conn <- connections[order(connections$name, connections$time), ]
      conn <- split(conn, conn$name)
      conn <- parLapply(cl, conn, calculate_duration)
      conn <- do.call("rbind", conn)
      conn
    },
    dplyr = {
      connections %>% 
        arrange(name, time) %>% 
        group_by(name) %>% 
        mutate(end_time = lead(time)) %>% 
        filter(state == "on") %>% 
        mutate(duration = difftime(end_time, time))
    },
    times = 10
  )

  message(sprintf("Benchmark for %s groups:", 
                  length(unique(connections$name))))

  print(out)
}
```

> ```
> Benchmark for 3 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
>      base 1.387948 1.390001 1.481524 1.491905 1.564191  1.587064    10
>  parallel 3.535705 4.435393 4.557561 4.734508 4.965587  5.136552    10
>     dplyr 3.222515 3.272074 4.515245 3.534385 3.676465 13.978893    10
>
> Benchmark for 30 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>      base 10.800952 11.201530 12.020516 11.339943 11.670142 15.609064    10
>  parallel  9.992464 10.990684 11.496216 11.497125 12.073653 12.782729    10
>     dplyr  5.699297  6.019231  6.056093  6.092104  6.127148  6.347964    10
>
> Benchmark for 150 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>      base 53.52881 54.47601 57.01772 56.41424 58.62636 63.47641    10
>  parallel 35.42127 37.91183 39.10031 39.05301 39.89185 42.53285    10
>     dplyr 17.31812 17.52427 19.01509 17.93761 19.95384 24.30478    10
>
> Benchmark for 300 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>      base 111.00359 114.57917 119.35063 117.68527 123.43090 131.21256    10
>  parallel  71.35337  72.95979  76.53514  76.74857  79.88487  84.47363    10
>     dplyr  31.50023  32.21957  33.53007  33.71852  34.38932  36.30571    10
>
> Benchmark for 1500 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
>      base 647.6213 677.7236 692.9642 687.5113 725.7461 741.0704    10
>  parallel 423.8719 437.3221 485.8728 449.2985 506.2456 627.6593    10
>     dplyr 159.6991 166.2746 171.3379 169.5461 173.5134 187.0929    10
>
> Benchmark for 6000 groups:
> Unit: milliseconds
>      expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
>      base 3454.545 3517.1275 3616.9079 3579.5780 3773.7299 3789.4571    10
>  parallel 2506.242 2556.1848 2601.5728 2607.1978 2639.6757 2695.3605    10
>     dplyr  657.422  681.0403  704.7698  691.7343  713.3387  784.5798    10
> ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try all that. My duration function:

```r
duration<-function(table){
  t<-as.duration(diff(table$time))
  t<-cbind(table,session_duration=c(0,t))
  t<-t[t$session_duration > 0,]
  
  return(t)
}
```
Very basic and based on base package.

Comment: The `dplyr` version is much faster on my data ... I need to learn how to really use it. Started to look at `datatable`. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Just to follow up, I tinkered with your code a little and concluded that `as.duration` was the biggest bottleneck.  I think you would have been mostly okay if you had skipped that conversion.  But it still wouldn't have been as quick as `dplyr`.  Glad you've got it working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah this duration function was a brute force method. 
I took the opportunity to look at dplyr doc since then. Managed to get further in my work, aggregating per user and per hour, getting counts, max and so on. Thanks a lot for the solution and the pointer toward the right package.